# REGEXPR_REPLACE string

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

How to replace `&` in the below string:

```
'extends the functionality & of the & REPLACE function & by'
```

with `one`, `two` and `three` respectively.

In the end the result should be:

```
extends the functionality one of the two REPLACE function three by
```

Comment: SAP HANA database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a nested REPLACE_REGEXPR function and always replace the first (next) remaining match with a different string.

```
SELECT REPLACE_REGEXPR
       ('&' IN REPLACE_REGEXPR 
               ('&' IN REPLACE_REGEXPR
                      ('&' IN 'extends the functionality & of the & REPLACE function & by'
                        WITH 'one' OCCURRENCE 1) 
                 WITH 'two' OCCURRENCE 1)  
         WITH 'three' OCCURRENCE 1) "replace_regexpr" 
FROM DUMMY;
```

Answer (score 1):

(A bit late, but) a version using one REPLACE_REGEXPR:

```sql
SELECT
    REPLACE_REGEXPR(
        '([^&]*)&([^&]*)&([^&]*)&([^&]*)'
        IN 'extends the functionality & of the & REPLACE function & by'
        WITH '\1one\2two\3three\4') "replace_regexpr"
FROM DUMMY
;
```

Out:

```
replace_regexpr                                                    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------|
extends the functionality one of the two REPLACE function three by |
```